# Merge two views into third view

Tags: mysql

I currently have two views with the same columnnames each containing thier part of the result.
I would like to merge these into a third view. There is no duplicates values. How is this done in MySQL 5.6?

```
SELECT * FROM viewcons1
UNION
SELECT * FROM viewcons2
```

The above returns only one tuple but should return 4000+ tuples.

Edit I tried UNION ALL and it works but I can't add it to a third view:

```
CREATE VIEW thirdview AS
SELECT * FROM viewcons1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM viewcons2
```

Comment: Some magic? You can use UNION ALL for performance(this can't make sense on result set if you haven't duplicates).

Comment: Everything is correct - it is probably wrong code in processing and showing result. Try it with sql client or post your code here.

Comment: Note of caution: _Never_ do `SELECT *` in a union query, even when you are sure the tables have the same structure.  Always be explicit about the order of columns returned in the `SELECT` list. (actually, it isn't really good practice to use `SELECT *` in production code at all)

Comment: I can't seem to create a third view as described in the updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by merging the two views into a new table since merging two views into a third view isen't possible using the mentioned syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM view_1 UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM view_2;
```

I know that SELECT * should not be in production code.

Alles bestens.